# Using external commands in vim map-operator function

Tags: vim

I'd like to create a vim mapping that allows for motions to control what text to output. There doesn't seem to be a whole lot of documentation on this and I'm having trouble adapting [the sample in vim's help page](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#%3amap-operator) to what I need. Here's what I have, which gives no errors but does not replace the text. What am I missing?

```
nmap ,s :set opfunc=CustomFunc<cr>g@

function! CustomFunc(type, ...)
    let sel_save = &selection
    let &selection = "inclusive"
    let reg_save = @@

    if a:type == 'line'
        silent exe "normal! '[V']!sort"
    elseif a:type == 'block'
        silent exe "normal! `[\<C-V>`]!sort"
    else
        silent exe "normal! `[v`]!sort"
    endif

    let &selection = sel_save
    let @@ = reg_save
endfunction
```

I used `!sort` as a very simple example for testing. The idea here is you could have a block like:

```
{
    Hello, World!
    Hello, Earth!
    Hello, Planet!
}
```

If you were to then move the cursor somewhere in the {} block and type `,si{` it would replace the block with

```
{
    Hello, Earth!
    Hello, Planet!
    Hello, World!
}
```

The workaround would be `vi{:!sort<cr>`, or if you have `vmap ,s :!sort` then `vi{,s`, but it would be nice to have this as an operator mapping (less typing, more flexible, etc).

Comment: Instead of using `!`, use the `system` function to transform the text.  An example of using `system` in this context can be found [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Act_on_text_objects_with_custom_functions).  Also, the `TextTransform` plugin will save you from having to manually write operator functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think external filtering with `:!` can ever be anything else then linewise.

*If you require something like that, I think you need to resort to things like the `system` function and "manually" manipulate the buffer contents, instead of relying on Vim's filtering command.*

And in the linewise case, the following, much simpler, incantation fixes it:

```
'[,']!sort
```

That is, instead of `silent exe "normal! '[V']!sort"`. I reckon the additional mode-switching implied with exec/`normal` kills the operator-pending mode (?).

```
{
    Hello, World!
    Hello, Earth!
    Hello, Planet!
}
```

*(cursor on `W`, type <kbd>,</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>):*

```
{
    Hello, Earth!
    Hello, Planet!
    Hello, World!
}
```

Comment: That's excellent! Any idea if the selection_save and reg_save will bite me if I take it out? I now have a oneline function with `silent exe "'[,']!sort"` that works great.

Comment: I don't feel qualified to conjecture about selection_save/reg_save without further studying...

Answer (score 1):

Ex commands are always linewise, so it doesn't easily work what you want. There are some plugins, that help you with that (e.g. Dr. Chips [VIS plugin](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/#VIS) or my [NrrwRgn](https://github.com/chrisbra/NrrwRgn) plugin. But I am not sure, if they help you in that particular case of omaps.